# Powerpoint changes mission control desktops every time I focus on a window

Tags: macos, ms-office, mission-control

I'm trying to use PowerPoint on my Mac with Mountain Lion. I have a window that was originally opened in Desktop 1 and then I moved it to Desktop 4. Now, whenever I try to focus on the window in Desktop 4, it auto-switches back to Desktop 1, preventing me from actually doing anything in PowerPoint. The key here seems to be that I've turned off the System Preference in the Mission Control tab to switch to a tab with an open window when I switch to an application. When I check that box, everything works as expected. That's a horrible solution though. Has anyone figured out a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to add a third party app to your Mac, use [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com) to assign apps to specific spaces. For example...

[image]

Comment: That is nice, clean, and quick answer :) (+1)

Comment: I do actually use TotalSpaces and it's very nice. However, that's not really the answer I'm looking for. The problem is that PowerPoint doesn't behave correctly at all. Every other app is perfectly happy to move between Desktops except Powerpoint. Maybe this question doesn't have a solution and it should just be submitted as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Possibly so. When I get time tonight, I am going to try to emulate your issue, as in the limited time I have had thus far, it's done fine for me.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue too (including the Systems Pref setting), and PowerPoint behaved properly when I moved it around my various Spaces.  I'm using PowerPoint 2011 (14.3.6) on Mountain Lion (10.8.4).  Are you using the same version of PPT and ML?